# Python: reading csv file and plotting but columns combined with column1 containing word and number

Tags: python, csv, txt

I am reading a csv file that looks like this
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQD84.png). The columns are separated by space/comma (I am able to do both). I have been able to read and separate the columns using the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('comma.csv',skipinitialspace=True, header=None, usecols=[0,1], names=['colA', 'colB'])
print df
```

The issue that I am currently facing is my columnA contains the word "Slice" before the main number. I want to remove it and then sort it according to the main number (ascending order) to plot it.

I have looked at different forums regarding splitting but unable to get it working. For instance:

```
temp = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)") 
res = temp.match(test_str).groups()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-splitting-text-and-number-in-string/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the column is a string and contains values like "Slice1" right?
If so (and this always the case) I think you could simply use  the string replace function.

```
firstvalue = "Slice1"
col_value = int(firstvalue.replace("Slice", ""))
```

Note, this is making some assumptions. For instance, this only works if the initial value is exactly like above. Lower case slice (like "slice1") will not work. It will also assume that the result can be safely parsed as an integer, so things like "Slices1" will also not work.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Yes, col1/A is a string with always the word Slice followed by the slice number eg: Slice32. However, my first row is not always Slice1. Also your code wrongs perfectly well when just trying for a single string but how can I do this for the entire column? I tried replacing "Slice1" with "colA" but no lucl.

Comment: Ah, now I see more what you meant. I have not worked with pandas so I can't say which python type a "column" is, but if it simply a list of strings you could iterate over it and then sort it. Also in order to make "Slice1" into "1", you should use exactly my code (e.g. .replace("Slice","") which will actually replace the instance of the word Slice with an empty string, effectively removing it.